# Display Android NDK Nativewindow by using openGL shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, ffmpeg, android-ndk, gpu

I am using ffmpeg in Android NDK for research purpose. And the source code is using the method below to display the frame on screen:

```
ANativeWindow* window = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, javaSurface);

ANativeWindow_Buffer buffer;
if (ANativeWindow_lock(window, &buffer, NULL) == 0) {
  memcpy(buffer.bits, pixels,  w * h * 2);
  ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(window);
}

ANativeWindow_release(window);
```

which is described [here](https://vec.io/posts/how-to-render-image-buffer-in-android-ndk-native-code).

I would like to do some image processing (ex: enhance the contrast) before the frame display on the screen, and I know OpenGL shader can modify the pixels values efficiently by processing on GPU.

But I can't figure out how to use shader to display Nativewindow.

Comment: Right now you're drawing on the Surface by copying bytes into a memory buffer. To take advantage of the GPU, you'll either need to process with bytes with a compute shader, or upload the bytes with `glTexImage2D()` and then render them with GLES instead.

Comment: As to the relevant advice to give on texture streaming, is your device ES 2 or 3?

Comment: Thank you fadden, I will try the second method. Pass the byte array to java layer through jni, and use OpenGL to render it.



@Tommy my device is Acer Liquid S1